# FCM notifications working on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am totally unable to get FCM notifications working on Firefox, while it perfectly works on Chrome.

When I ask the Firebase SDK to return the current authentication token, the promise returns "null" which means that it wasn't able to get it. Mostly due to some permission stuff.

```
console.log(Notification.permission);
```

Print "default" which, according to the official documentation, means the same as "denied".

If I try to use either `firebase.messaging().requestPermission()` or the browser version of the permission request, promise never resolve and I don't see any popup asking for permission.

My manifest.json does include the "notifications" in the permission field.

I launch the extension on Firefox using `web-ext`

I'm kinda desperate, this is incredible that making web extensions working is such difficult.

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any error whenever you are trying to replicate the issue? It could be helpful for the community to check your problem.

Comment: @Teldar did you get it to work? Could you share the service worker setup code?

Answer (score 0):

The Web Notifications API works slightly different from the `browser.notifications` API. In order to use the `Notifications` API, one must first ask permission to the user as shown in this example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Example). This is something you would do in a normal web page.

To use notifications in a browser extension, you have to set `notifications` permission in the manifest file and then **create a new notification** with [browser.notifications.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/create).
This will not prompt a window popup to the user asking to allow notifications, because this permission was already granted in the manifest file.